# Help a not too-tech-savvy-soul set his screen resolution in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, display, screen, display-resolution, monitor

I'm not completely clueless but I can't seem to fix this one.

I'm stuck picking 1028x768 or 800x600.  I'd really like 1600x1050 which is what I always had but it won't let me do that.  I'm using a 48" HDTV as a monitor and never had a problem before.  On older versions of ubuntu if this happened I'd plug in a standard 22" monitor and hit "detect display" and it would default to 1600x1050.  Not so with 16.04.

What must one do to fix this, good people?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/854427/edit) your post  and add output of `xrandr` command

Comment: 48" HDTV are usually limited to 1920x1080.

Comment: care to say something about your hardware, in particular the graphics card?